# Using different packages for Controllers when using in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, controller

I am new in Spring boot.I trying to access the controller url but i didn't get any response from them.

We are followed spring boot project structure as per document.
I have used componentscan annotation and added scanBasePackageClasses in SpringBootApplication annotation.But still same.

**HomeController :-**

```
package com.main.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/home",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("home");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**GAppsApplication.java:-**

```
package com.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import com.main.controllers.HomeController;
@ComponentScan({"com.main.controllers"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses={HomeController.class})
public class GAppsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GAppsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

For your reference i shared below logs
logs:-

```
2018-08-28 08:26:16.404  INFO 8172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@58b9d6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@525747, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1638752, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@324c61, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@14a6743, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@12d6ce4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@1837d01, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@eda2d2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4a5109, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4bb38c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@12205be, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2e4343, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1a81a58, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@12e7437]
2018-08-28 08:26:16.558  INFO 8172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-08-28 08:26:16.592  INFO 8172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-08-28 08:26:16.594  INFO 8172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-08-28 08:26:16.600  INFO 8172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-08-28 08:26:16.638  INFO 8172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-28 08:26:16.642  INFO 8172 --- [  restartedMain] c.main.GAppsApplication                  : Started GAppsApplication in 5.153 seconds (JVM running for 5.734)
2018-08-28 08:27:11.961  INFO 8172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-08-28 08:27:11.961  INFO 8172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-08-28 08:27:11.980  INFO 8172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
```

Comment: Looks like you done need explicit `ComponentScan` and `scanBasePackageClasses`. Something must be wrong the way you are executing the GET request. Can you share details about the request part

Comment: I am simple call http://localhost:8080/home from browser.I didn't get any response and System.out.println is not printed in the console.

Comment: Have you visited this URL[https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/] to learn how to  build a web service? BTW, `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`, so you don't need to specify any of them again.

Comment: Yes you said correct.Its not required to define ComponentScan annotation.But I am tried this one. I have used eclipse Oxygen with spring source suite plugins.I created different project and define a controller in the same package then able to access url and print the System.out.println also.

Comment: There is a difference between `@Controller` and `@RestController`. Looks like you want a RestFul service and for that you should use `@RestController`

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to like below :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("home");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

As your base package is `com.main`, so any package within `com.main` will automatically be scanned.

You don't need to put any special annotation to scan.